# Wie kommt es zu den Präfixen "all-", "alle-", "aller-" und "allen-"?

Tags: etymology, adjective, prefix, conjugation, inflection

Basierend auf der Wurzel [**all**](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=all), einem alten Wort für "umfassend" und "ganz", werden eine ganze Reihe von Adjektiven gebildet. Interessanterweise ändert sich dabei das Präfix wie folgt:

> - **all-:**
>     alltäglich, allgemein
> - **alle-:**
>     allemal, allesamt
> - **aller-:**
>     allerdings, allerlei
> - **allen-:**
>     allenfalls, allenthalben
> - ***variabel:***
>     allseits/allseitig, allerseits

Meine Vermutung ist, dass es sich hierbei um eine unterschiedliche Beugung handelt. Stimmt meine Vermutung, oder gibt es noch andere Gründe, weshalb es hier so viele verschiedene Präfixe gibt?

Comment: Könnte es nicht einfach Fugen (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortfuge) sein?

Comment: allseits, allseitig und allerseits heißen nicht das selbe. Warum sollten sie eine eigene Gruppe kriegen?

Comment: @Emanuel: Weil sie eine andere Bedeutung haben, bin ich bei allseits/allerseits erst auf die Idee gekommen, es könnte sich um Beugung handeln ;)

Comment: Das ist ja allerhand ...

Comment: Eigentlich eine recht interessante Frage. Mir fällt noch  Alltagssprache und Allerseelen ein. Eindeutige Erklärungen dürften hier wohl kaum zu finden sein. Eher ein Problem für eine Doktorarbeit. Bei allemal könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass ein Plural zugrunde lag, "alle Male", bei dem Male zu -mal reduziert wurde.

Comment: Die Bedeutung ist die gleiche, aber die Fälle und der Numerus sind unterschiedlich.

Answer (score 1):

> **Alle** Welt ...
>   Nominativ / Akkusativ
>
> Aus aller ** Welt ...
>   Genitiv (?)
>
> **Allen** falls
>   Ebenfalls Genitiv? Vgl. „keine **s** falls“
>
> Vor **allen** Leuten ...
>   Dativ

Ich glaube, du hast schon recht ...